# State returns an empty array even after setting in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen similar questions on SO but have not been able to identify the issue I'm having.

I have a useState variable that I set in useEffect on first load. Then, **at a much later time** an event fires and within the event I check the value of the variable and it's always an empty array []. However, I added a second useEffect to track the changes in my state variable and I don't see where it's being emptied. Here's some code to highlight my issue:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { DragAndDrop } from "../components";

const AddKidPage = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    var f = [
      "nice.pdf",
      "verycool.jpg",
      "amazing.png",
      "goodstuff.mp3",
      "thankyou.doc",
    ];

    setFiles(f);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(files);
  }, [files]);

  const handleDrop = (newFiles) => {
    let fileList = files;

    // HERE FILES = []

    for (var i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {
      if (!newFiles[i].name) return;
      fileList.push(newFiles[i].name);
    }

    setFiles(fileList);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <DragAndDrop handleDrop={handleDrop}>
        <div style={{ height: 300, width: 250 }}>
          {files.map((file, i) => (
            <div key={i}>{file}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </DragAndDrop>
    </main>
  );
};

export default AddKidPage;
```

I have 1 console.log in the file-tracking useEffect. Here is the output when the component mounts:

[]

["nice.pdf", "verycool.jpg", "amazing.png", "goodstuff.mp3", "thankyou.doc"]

This makes sense - I'm initializing the array as empty then I immediately fill it with values which then triggers the second output. However, here is the output AFTER I drop a file (this causes handleDrop() to execute):

["newFile.png"]

As you can see ALL other values were wiped out. My comment in code "HERE FILES = []" demonstrates where the files useState is still empty even though my output shows it was filled. The useEffect never outputs an empty array a second time so where is it being emptied? Am I retrieving the value wrong? Any help with this mystery is greatly appreciated. I opted to not show the code for DragAndDrop component but it seems solid and calls the handleDrop method at the right time and with correct values.

EDIT:

Although DragAndDrop seems solid, this could be some sort of issue with how I'm calling the passed in function... or my use of {children}. I'm not sure. So, here is the code for DragAndDrop which completes this component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const DragAndDrop = ({ handleDrop: externalDrop, children }) => {
  const [drag, setDrag] = useState(false);
  const [dragCounter, setDragCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleDrag = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  const handleDragIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    setDragCounter(dragCounter + 1);
    if (e.dataTransfer.items && e.dataTransfer.items.length > 0) {
      setDrag(true);
    }
  };

  const handleDragOut = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    setDragCounter(dragCounter - 1);
    if (dragCounter - 1 === 0) {
      setDrag(false);
    }
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    setDrag(false);
    if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
      externalDrop(e.dataTransfer.files);
      e.dataTransfer.clearData();
      setDragCounter(0);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    var div = document.getElementById("draganddrop-wrapper");

    div.addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragIn);
    div.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragOut);
    div.addEventListener("dragover", handleDrag);
    div.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop);

    return () => {
      div.removeEventListener("dragenter", handleDragIn);
      div.removeEventListener("dragleave", handleDragOut);
      div.removeEventListener("dragover", handleDrag);
      div.removeEventListener("drop", handleDrop);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper id="draganddrop-wrapper">
      {drag && (
        <div className="drag-hover">
          <div className="drag-overlay">
            <div>drop here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      {children}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  .drag-hover {
    border: dashed grey 4px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    .drag-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      color: grey;
      font-size: 36px;
    }
  }
`;

export default DragAndDrop;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are mutating the `files` variable instead of cloning it.

Change

```
let fileList = files;
```

to

```
const fileList = [...files];
```

---

Update

```
const handleDrop = useCallback((newFile) => {
    if (newFile.type === "image/png") {
        setFile(newFile.name);
    }
}, []);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-app-test-djppl?file=/src/App.jsx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and the results are the same. I added this code: const fileList = [...files]; console.log(fileList); and the output I get is [].

Comment: Try to change `const fileList = [...files];` to `let fileList = [...files];`

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior is the same with let.

Comment: I've modified my question to include the other component. I'm not sure if it's to blame but figured I'd add it.

Comment: @BrianLegg You're saying that the first time `handledrop` is called after the component mounts, the `files` array is `console.log` as empty in the `// HERE...` comment? The `DragAndDrop` component would be irrelevant since it doesn't directly interact with `files` array. Can you provide a sample of your code on codesandbox?

Comment: I've never used code sandbox but I'll try to set it up. But yes, the array is console.log empty array after the first time handledrop is called. And every time after as well. My requirements actually changed and I only require 1 file now so I'm ok now. This is now just a matter of curiosity at this point.

Comment: @SILENT - I tried for a couple hours but still can't get codepen to work. It says there are no errors and nothing in console but it doesn't display anything. Here's a link though, incase you're more familiar with codepen than I. https://codepen.io/saltysquid/pen/ExNzvrZ

Comment: @BrianLegg Its codesandbox.io. Codepen is more limited. They have default react templates you can use it get up and running in a few minutes.

Comment: @BrianLegg I made a version of it - https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-app-test-djppl?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: @BrianLegg I've reconfigured it to get it working. Certain issues like not using some of react's cache abilities to prevent useEffect from re-rendering, etc may have caused problems previously.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much - marking as accepted!